# What is andFilterWhere() condition operands purpose?

Tags: yii2

I'm absolutely new to `Yii2 framework`. I'm trying to learn filtering, but somehow I don't understand it. I've looked in the documentation, but it didn't helped too. Could someone explain to me what this function does step by step?

```
public function filteringValues($query)
{   
        $query->andFilterWhere([
            '>',
            'table1.column1',
            date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
        ]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

just like the [doc](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-querytrait.html#andFilterWhere()-detail) points out, `andFilterWhere` applies a condition **if the operands are not empty**

in your particular case (since `date('Y-m-d H:i:s')` always returns a value),

```
$query->andFilterWhere(['>', 'table1.column1', date('Y-m-d H:i:s')]);
```

will be equivalent to

```
$query->andWhere(['>', 'table1.column1', date('Y-m-d H:i:s')]);
```

which is translated to sql to a condtion like

```
AND (`table1`.`column1`) > '2017-08-12 06:10:32'
```

---

a propper use case for `andFilterWhere` is when comparing with an optional value (received as a filter param).

```
$query->andFilterWhere(['>', 'table1.column1', $date]);
```

it's purpose is to not have to check whether `$date` is empty or not

```
$query->andFilterWhere([
    'table1.column1' => $param1,
    'table1.column2' => $param2,
    'table1.column3' => $param3,
]);
```

in this example, the query applies a condtion only for the params that are not [empty](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-querytrait.html#isEmpty()-detail), ignoring the extra ones